# Spring Quartz | Mariadb

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am trying to use Spring Quartz implementation, but the table names created are lowercase.
I am using the QRTZ_ as prefix and all the table names are being accessed with Capital case.
So, I am unable to access the table since it's created with lowercase.
Is there any mechanism in Spring Boot, which can rename the table to lowercase while querying the QRTZ tables?

Is this issue with database configuration?

Regards
Atul

Comment: please provide the sprig.quartz configuration here

Comment: @VladimirShefer - Please find below the pom.xml ```  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent> <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>```